# Open up content in another div with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some content I wish to load into a div using Angular. For example:

```
<div class="number-and-description" ng-controller="thingDetails">                               
                                    <div class="number" ng-click="loadContent(thing.number, thing.description, thing.status)" ng-cloak>{{ thing.number }}</div>


                                    <p class="description" ng-click="loadContent(thing.number, thing.description, thing.status)" ng-cloak>{{ thing.description }}</p>
                                </div>
```

I have another view outside of this div like this:

```
<!-- Main Content Area -->
            <section class="main-content group" ng-controller="thingDetails">                   
                <h1 ng-cloak>{{ thingNumber }}</h1>
                <div ng-cloak>{{ thingDescription }}</div>
                <div ng-cloak>{{ thingStatus }}</div>

            </section>
```

In my app.js file, I have this code:

```
thingApp.controller('thingDetails', ["$scope", function($scope) {

  $scope.loadContent = function(number, description, status) {

      $scope.thingNumber      = number;
      $scope.thingDescription = description;
      $scope.thingStatus      = status;




      return $scope;

  };



}]);
```

My question is, why doesn't the main content area div update when these values are changed? Right now it remains blank. thing.number, thing.description loads fine in the div I am clicking on - this data is coming from hardcoded JSON which appears fine. The issue is that when I click on the div, the OTHER main content div doesn't show/update the data. Could someone please help me out? Note that when I `console.log(number)` or `console.log(description)` etc. I can see the correct values, so they are being passed correctly to the `loadContent()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two separate instances of controller `thingDetails` , not one. They each have their own scope and do not share anything directly. A simple way to see this is put a `console.log()` in your controller and you will see it run each time the controller initializes

For controllers to share data you use a service and inject that service wherever it needs to be accessed.

Alternatively perhaps you don't need two instances and can wrap them in one scope in your view

Answer (score 0):

You are basically creating two controllers here with two different scopes.  Thus, in the outer div, $scope.thingNumber, description, etc. are undefined as you are only changing the values on the inner scope.

A quick but messy fix to this problem would be to change your $scope's to $rootScopes.  The proper way to do this though is via services/factories.